# strdup() causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

I have the following code:

```
char *passwordFunc(const char *s)
{
    static char *pw = NULL;
    if (strlen(s)) {
        pw = s;
    } 
    return pw;
}

void keyboard_interactive(const char *name, int name_len, const char *instr, int instr_len, 
                          int num_prompts, const LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_PROMPT *prompts, LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_RESPONSE *res, 
                          void **abstract)
{
    char *text = passwordFunc("");
    res[0].text = strdup(text);
    res[0].length = strlen(text);
}
```

According to the debugger, every time it gets to the line with `strdup(text)`, it crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)`.

Any suggestions as to what is happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `passwordFunc` function? For any non-empty string, it returns its argument; for an empty string, it returns a null pointer. That doesn't seem useful. What if you just drop the `passwordFunc` function altogether, and change the first declaration in `keyboard_interactive` to `char *text = "";`?

Comment: Is `res` a valid pointer to write to?

Comment: How can I check that? `keyboard_interactive` is a libssh2 callback so I don't see why it wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 4):

`passwordFunc("")` is returning `NULL`. When you pass that to `strdup`, you get a segmentation fault because `strdup` expects a valid C string. That the error message refers to address `0x0` is indication that the program is de-referencing the null pointer.

Now, `passwordFunc("")` returns `NULL` because `strlen("")` is zero and zero evaluates as false.

Some implementations of `strdup` return the empty string when passed `NULL`. It seems that this code was written assuming such an implementation. Your compiler's library behaves differently.

You can probably fix the code most easily by providing your own implementation of `strdup` that behaves the way that this code assumes.

```
char *strdup(const char *s) {
    size_t len = (s == NULL) ? 1 : strlen(s) + 1;
    char *result = malloc(len);  
    if (result != NULL) 
        if (len>1)
            memcpy(result, s, len);                       
        else
            *result = 0;
    return result;                           
}
```

As an aside, I would comment that `passwordFunc` should really return `const char*` rather than `char*` and likewise `pw` should be `const char*`. Your compiler probably warns you about this and you should heed those warnings.

Comment: @Keith Thompson and David Heffernan I'm not exactly sure what the function is doing myself. The file is a wrapper on libssh2. The whole file is here: https://github.com/gonzopancho/libssh2-for-iOS/blob/74f58c146c9556789c9297a9c7d8a3818472cabf/Classes/SSHWrapper.m . I can't change the arguments to keyboard_interactive because that function is a callback in libssh2 for logging in with the keyboard-interactive mode. My best guess as to what is happening in passwordFunc is that it is called earlier to save the password into the static var, and then called in keyboard_interactive to retrieve it.

Comment: I added an NSLog to log the password string that passwordFunc returned, and it was the correct password, so could it be the `res[0].text` part?

Comment: But `NSLog(@"%s", res[0].text);` causes the same error, so wouldn't it have to be something to do with `res[0]` that is triggering it?

Comment: If `res[0].text` contains `NULL`, then, once again, de-referencing `NULL` will lead to a seg fault. You cannot de-reference `NULL`. I don't know how to make the point any more clearly than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you callback function sometimes gets called, even if there was no prompt. So you need to make sure if you have to set something on the `res` object.

This code snippet will solve your problem:

```
void keyboard_interactive(const char *name, int name_len, const char *instr, int instr_len, 
                          int num_prompts, const LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_PROMPT *prompts, LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_RESPONSE *res, 
                          void **abstract)
{
    if( num_prompts > 0 ) {
        res[0].text = strdup(passwordFunc(""));
        res[0].length = strlen(passwordFunc(""));
    }
}
```